# If you attended TASTI 2023, which talks might you find particularly interesting/informative?

Tags: discussion

[TASTI 2023](https://tasti2023.com/) (Taiwan International Assembly of Space Science, Technology, and Industry) runs all next week in Taipei. There will be many talks - some days have several parallel sessions. ([keynote speakers](https://tasti2023.com/program/keynote-speakers)).

Because of the [Taiwan Space Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_Space_Agency) (formerly NPSO)'s big footprint in the GNSS signal occultation measurement of atmospheric water vapor for weather prediction via the FORMOSAT program and now with the successful launch of [TRITON/FORMOSAT 7R](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/formosat-7r.htm) many of the talks by both US' NOAA and Taiwan's space agency and meteorological community will somewhat dominate the conference. However there will be presentations by several other space interests, including about the [Advance Rocket Research Center](https://arrc.tw/)'s upcoming hover tests and eventual launches.

I'm overwhelmed by all the choices, so I'd like to ask this meta question:

**Question:** If you attended TASTI 2023, which talks might you find particularly interesting/informative?

Comment: In Astronomy Meta there are not-the-same-but-somewhat-similar "soft questions" of this general class, so I think this may be sufficiently on-topic here. [What are your plans for the Annular Solar Eclipse on October 14th, 2023?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/932/7982) and [Post your pictures of the Beaver Moon Lunar Eclipse here!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/816/7982) and [Post your pictures of the Great Conjunction here!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/651/7982) (also posted in [Earthscience SE](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2010/6031))

Comment: If I were there, I would definitely hit that Mars Sample Return session on Wednesday. I'd go to the SPIRE presentation on Thursday just because of the speaker's name.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The sample return talk was absolute top on my list. Sadly, I could not make it :-( Maybe it's for the better though, I probably would have drank too much coffee, raised my hand and started blithering about [escaping martian megaviruses and the end of the world](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45035/12102).

Comment: @OrganicMarble The president of Taiwan did make a surprise visit the first day and announced another boost to [TASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_Space_Agency)'s budget and plans for a launch facility, following the successful launch and deployment of TRITON/Formosat 7R ([1](https://www.tasa.org.tw/inprogress.php?c=20030305&ln=en), [2](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/formosat-7r.htm)) but these are long-term goals.